# why is my get request working, but not my post request?

Tags: javascript, express

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.listen(4000)

app.post('/items', function (req, res) {
res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})

app.get('/items', function (req, res) {
  res.send('gett request to the homepage')
})
```

this is the code and always, my get request works but my post request gives an error : cannot GET/

Comment: This is working perfectly, you need to check your post request.

Comment: This is working for me. Please show the code doing the POST, and tell us where that code is (presumably on a page served from this same Express server).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a ***very*** active place. When you post a question (or an answer), please *stick around* so you can respond to comments.

Comment: I am sorry. also i don't understand what you mean, this is the entire code,

Comment: Please tell us how you're doing the POST, and what **exact** error or similar you're seeing. (Probably best to copy and paste from the network tab in devtools -- assuming you're using a browser for the request. Or similar in whatever tool you are using.) Again: The above works.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. I changed the method in postman